# Android share file

Tags: android

I'm having trouble sharing a file I downloaded. The code I have right now is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

The file is in the external cache dir `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/lt.segfoltas.breathcount/cache/temp_chart.html`

The chooser opens, but none of the applications can handle it. ES explorer gives me "file not found", others fail in a similar way. I'd use the `DownloadManager`, but I get this file via `POST`. I haven't tried using a `FileProvider` or the media store, but those seem like the next options.

My main requirement right now is to get a file and give it to the user. What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: What does "give it to the user" mean? This is not how you use `ACTION_SEND`. If you switch it to `ACTION_VIEW`, and get rid of the `addFlags()`, you would have valid code to view the file, at least until Android N ships.

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW` works, but it only gives me a few apps that allow viewing. I need to send it somewhere, like Dropbox or email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tactically, change your code to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

following [the documentation for `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

Strategically, since [sharing files is being discontinued](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html), add [a `FileProvider` to serve your file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), as shown in [the sharing files documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: I was just writing an answer with this code. Thanks, and I'll look into the changes. Isn't [MediaStore.Files](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html) also a valid solution, especially if you don't want to hide your files from the user?

Comment: @DariusL: "Isn't MediaStore.Files also a valid solution..." -- I'm not a fan. I consider `MediaStore` to be read-only. Various people have been using it for read-write, and I wish them luck.

Answer (score 2):

**Update your code with below code:-**

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
 shareIntent.setType("text/html");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share"));
```

Comment: Sorry, the other guy was 5 minutes earlier